# Proving that $\displaystyle{\lim _{n\to\infty}} \frac{1}{n^2} = 0$ using limit arithmetic

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be the index of sequence $\{\frac{1}{n^2}\}_{n=1}^\infty$.

I'm assuming that:
$$\displaystyle{\lim _{n\to\infty}} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\displaystyle{\lim _{n\to\infty}} 1}{\displaystyle{\lim _{n\to\infty}}n^2}, \displaystyle{\lim _{n\to\infty}}n^2 \neq 0$$

The problem is, after I prove that the limit of the numerator is 1, I cannot prove that the denominator has a limit because it's a fluttering/divergent sequence. Having no limit, and striving towards infinity, how can I possibly do limit arithmetic on them?

Comment: What is a fluttering sequence?

Comment: You can't assume lim (f/g) = lim(f)/lim(g) if lim(g) is not defined

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Forgot to include that, thanks.

Comment: Why can't you just use $1/\infty=0$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How I translated a non-converging sequence from my native tongue. A divergent sequence.

Comment: @Andrei I thought of that, but I was wondering if there was something more formal.

Comment: This should be enough, since it's not $\frac\infty\infty$ type of ratio. If you want to be more formal, use $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

Comment: Why not use the delta epsilon argument.  (I hate people saying things like $\frac 1\infty = 0$ but you do *know* that is so.)

Comment: What actually do you *know* about limits.  DO you even have a definition as to what a limit is?  If not you *can't* do this at all except to say "well, it's obvious".  A simple theory ought to be if $\lim f(x) = \pm \infty$ then $\lim \frac 1{f(x)} = 0$ but you need to have proven before you can use it.

Comment: I don't know what you do and do not know about limits. Would something like $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 1{n^2} = \lim_{\sqrt m\to \infty} \frac 1m=\lim_{m\to \infty} \frac1m=0$ be acceptable?  Or is that slick cheating?  Or is that avoiding the entire question by doing manipulations we don't understand to get the result?  Do you know *why* $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 1n = 0$?  Do you know *why* $\lim_{n\to \infty}n^2 =\infty$?  Do you know *why* $\lim_{n\to \infty} n = \infty$? Do we know what $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$ *means*? I'm not trying to be mean. But I do need to know what you background is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identity
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n}{\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n}$$
does not hold when the limits on the RHS don't exist (or when the limit in the denominator would be $0$). The limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^2$ does not exist as the sequence is divergent, so you can not use the above identity. A valid way way to do limit arithmetic would be
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\right).$$
In this case, interchanging limit and product is possible, because the limits on the RHS each exist. They, of course, evaluate to $0$ and hence so does the original limit.

Comment: How did you ever figure that $\lim \frac 1n = 0$ though in the first place?  .... I'm a bit confused about what the OP has and hasn't been taught about limits in the first place and what "arithmetic of limits" is supposed to mean?  Why is $\frac 1\infty = 0$ "bad" but $\lim \frac 1n = \infty$ utterly unquestioned?... Actually by this question, I don't even know if the OP has a definition of what a limit *means*.

Comment: I assume limit arithmetic refers to the standard results that if $\lim a_n=a,\lim b_n=b$, then $\lim(a_n+b_n)=a+b,\lim(a_nb_n)=ab$  and, granted $b\neq0$, $\lim(a_n/b_n)=a/b$. Of course, the limit $\lim 1/n=0$ has to be proven beforehand, but it is the single most archetypical example of a limit, usually presented right after the definition thereof, so if OP already knows limit arithmetic, I thought it's justified to assume that limit is known. Of course, I would've provided proof of that if requested.

Comment: I guess I'm finding second guessing these things as unquestioned givens is perplexing to me.  I have no idea what the OP has and has not been taught.  If we do all these things and take it for granted limits distribute over arithmetic without proving why, and even to use limits without actually defining what a limit *is*, then I don't see why we don't just go all the way with the handwaving and just teach $\frac 1{\infty} =0$ and $\frac 10 = \infty$.  They all seem like hand waving abuse of concept to me.

Comment: Well, when I looked at OP's question, what I saw was a misapplication of limit arithmetic due to neglecting the hypotheses, so the point of my answer was to restate that these arithmetic rules can't be applied mindlessly and an alternative way of how to use them to reduce the problem to something that is (or should be) already known. If OP is getting rigorous exposure to math, that will be congruent with what they've been taught. If that is not the case, I'm afraid hand-waving is inevitable at some point, though I fully agree with you that it is bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Just do delta-epsilon.  There's no trick.

For any $\epsilon> 0$ let $N \ge \frac 1{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$.

If $n > N$ then $|\frac 1{n^2} - 0| =\frac 1{n^2} < \frac 1{N^2} = \epsilon$.

So $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1{n^2} = 0$.

That's it.

=====

In general, you should have one time or another have been presented with a proof that

> if $\lim f(n) = +\infty$ then $\lim \frac 1{f(n)} = 0$.

The proof would be:  As $\lim_{n\to a|\infty} f(n)=+\infty$ then for any $N$ there is a condition for $n$ so that $f(n) > N$.  [If $\lim_{n\to a} f(n) = \infty$ the condition is there is a $\delta$ so tha $|n-a| < \delta$ will mean $f(n) >N$.  If $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n) = \infty$ the condition is there is a $M$ so that $n > M$ will mean $f(n) > N$].

For any $\epsilon > 0$ let $N = \frac 1{\epsilon}$ then if $n$ has the condition we know $f(n) > N$ so $\frac 1{f(n)} < \epsilon$.  So $\lim \frac 1{f(n)} = 0$.

....

So if we assume $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^2 = \infty$ (which is either very clear; or provable as for any $N>0$ if $n > \sqrt{N} \implies n^2 > N$) we know the $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1{n^2} = 0$.

This is why we *informally* say $\frac 1\infty = 0$.  But that is informal and too many people say it without knowing what it *means*.